# Dicrepancy between PATH variable seen in Gitbash and in Windows control panel

Tags: python, command-line, git-bash

I am taking my first steps in integrating the command line into my work with python.
I am working on Windows10 and using Gitbash within VScode.

The problem is that I can't figure out why the PATH variable is so different between what I get when using echo $PATH in gitbash vs. when I check it in the Windows control panel.
Also, some of the results I get indicate that the usr/local/bin folder, which I saw is the classical directory to place execuatble programs, does exist, while others make me think it doesn't exist.
Looking for a solution.

On gitbash when I do 'echo $PATH' I get the list of folders I thought I would (usr/bin, usr/local/bin etc).

But when I look at the PATH variable in Windows control panel, they are different: There's no usr/bin, usr/local/bin and so on.

However, when I add the shebang '#! usr/bin/env python3' to a program it allows it to run without using the python3 statement - which I understand means that the shebang worked (i.e., the specified folder does exist...). How then, could the usr/bin folder not exist??

On the other hand, when I try to copy a program to usr/local/bin, i get this message: 'cp: cannot create regular file '/usr/local/bin/': No such file or directory'

I would like to ask:

1. Do all of the classical directories for executables (usr/bin etc.) exist in my computer? I'm reading a book that says I should add the relevant programs to usr/local/bin, but I can't seem to do it.
2. If I don't have those paths- should I just copy files that I want to be executable into any of the directories specified as PATH in Windows control panel? so instead of 'cp file.py usr/local/bin' get used to doing 'cp file.py %SystemRoot%\system32'? Is there a specific directory that is recommend?
3. Are there any other major differences that I should know about?

Thanks!

Comment: git-bash uses msys to try to look like a UNIXy system. PATHs look different between UNIXy and Windows systems; shell scripts written for UNIX wouldn't work if git-bash didn't translate them. Which is to say -- this is as-designed. If you want to learn about your Windows system, you'll be better off using Windows-native tools that aren't responsible for trying to pretend that it's something it's not.

Comment: BTW, `#!/usr/bin/env python3` needs the `/`; `#! usr/bin/env python3` is wrong, and in a real UNIXy system it wouldn't work.

Comment: Anyhow -- (1) depends on definitions (what do you mean "in my computer"? If it only exists while you're running git-bash, does that mean it "exists" to you?); (2) is a question for your friendly local sysadmin, not for us (corporate policy will _often_ prohibit you from adding contents to system32; typically better practice is to install software for your personal account's use under your own home directory); (3) is too open-ended to be on-topic here, and is a place you should probably start by reading msys documentation.

Comment: _In general_, though, you're probably better off trying to follow Windows conventions, not UNIX conventions, when on Windows. msys will try to make things work while you do so, to the extent possible.